# CERBOT ContextualVersionConflict: (zope.interface 4.3.2 (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages)

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, aws-cli, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm trying to get an SSL certificate using `CERTBOT` through "`certbot-dns-route53`". I've install `certbot` , `aws-cli` and c`ertbot-dns-route53` plugin on `Ubuntu 18.0`

I fired the following command "certbot certonly --dns-route53 -d mydomain.com" and got the following error

```
    2021-04-24 13:05:20,028:DEBUG:certbot._internal.log:Exiting abnormally:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/certbot", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 15, in main
    return internal_main.main(cli_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/certbot/_internal/main.py", line 1403, in main
    plugins = plugins_disco.PluginsRegistry.find_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/certbot/_internal/plugins/disco.py", line 237, in find_all
    plugin_ep = cls._load_entry_point(entry_point, plugins, with_prefix=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/certbot/_internal/plugins/disco.py", line 255, in _load_entry_point
    plugin_ep = PluginEntryPoint(entry_point, with_prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/certbot/_internal/plugins/disco.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.plugin_cls: interfaces.IPluginFactory = entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2323, in load
    self.require(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2346, in require
    items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 783, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (zope.interface 4.3.2 (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('zope.interface>=5.3.0a1'), {'zope.component'})
2021-04-24 13:05:20,028:ERROR:certbot._internal.log:An unexpected error occurred:
2021-04-24 13:05:20,028:ERROR:certbot._internal.log:pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (zope.interface 4.3.2 (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('zope.interface>=5.3.0a1'), {'zope.component'})
```

Help me out here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in terminal:

```
> sudo apt remove certbot
> sudo snap remove certbot
> sudo pip uninstall certbot
> sudo pip3 uninstall certbot
```

then you run

```
> certbot
```

if ok you will get an error like:

```
> Command 'cerbot' not found, did you mean:
```

now, install certbot

```
> sudo apt install certbot
```

restart the terminal

Now, try if ok, run:

```
> certbot
```

if ok install certbot-dns-route53

```
> sudo apt install python3-certbot-dns-route53
```

Finally, restart the terminal and check to register your certificate.

This worked for me. ;)

Comment: Thanks @Nestor

I restarted my server after few hours and some how it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Could be recent apt update conflicting files. Follow procedure below; which worked for me; Assuming Ubuntu >= 18.0

```
 sudo apt-get remove certbot
 sudo pip3 uninstall certbot
 sudo pip uninstall certbot

 ## Install snap if not installed
 sudo snap install core; sudo snap refresh core  
 sudo snap install --classic certbot

 ## check for any previous symlink and link again.
 whereis certbot
 sudo ln -s /snap/bin/certbot /usr/bin/certbot
 sudo ln -s /snap/bin/certbot /usr/local/bin/certbot
```